# Twitter sharing with &amp; &

Tags: url, twitter

I try to share an url with a twitter button and everything is fine, except for urls that contain a `&` sign.

In these cases, the part of url after the & is just removed by twitter.

You can test that if you go on this example: 
http://www.daviddarx.com/stuffs/share_test_final/index.php?cat=test&subcat=test

The twitter link is go
http://twitter.com/?status=Test%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.daviddarx.com%2Fstuffs%2Fshare_test_final%2F , with a missing part of the adress.

Do yo know how to solve that? 
The url beeing modificated directly in the link and not by twitter itself, I guess that it's more a general problem about `&` in links, more than a twitter specific problem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I got it:

two solutions:
 -replace the & by %26, in the status url. 
 -use bit.ly to shorten urls, which may make sense on twitter.